# Changing the v-if in the same element to computed with it being reference to be used for other properties

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have been working on a sorting system lately with VueJs and Laravel but sort of got stuck on a piece of code that actually works, tho I don't think it's efficient because I'm using a v-if and a v-for in the same element. It is as following:

```
 <!-- Activity table (small breakpoint and up) -->
 <div class="hidden sm:block">
   <div class="max-w-6xl px-4 mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
     <div class="flex flex-col mt-2">
       <div class="min-w-full overflow-hidden overflow-x-auto align-middle shadow sm:rounded-lg">
         <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <th class="px-6 py-3 text-xs font-medium leading-4 tracking-wider text-left text-gray-500 uppercase bg-gray-50">
                                            Medewerker
               </th>
               <th class="px-6 py-3 text-xs font-medium leading-4 tracking-wider text-left text-gray-500 uppercase bg-gray-50">
                                            Laatst goedgekeurde datum
               </th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200" >
                                    
             <tr v-for="data in Medewerkers" :key="data.medewerkers" class="bg-white" v-if="data.timesheets.length !== 0">  <!-- This is the timesheet check function v-if="data.timesheets.length !== 0" -->
               <td class="px-6 py-3 text-xs font-medium leading-4 tracking-wider text-left text-gray-500 uppercase bg-gray-50">
                                            {{ data.mw_naam }}
               </td>
               <td class="px-6 py-3 text-xs font-medium leading-4 tracking-wider text-left text-gray-500 uppercase bg-gray-50">
                                            {{ data.timesheets[0].datum }}
               </td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

**My data object:**

```
data() {
  return {
    Medewerkers: null,
    aantalOpenstaande: null,
    laatstBijgewerkt: null,
  }
},
```

**My methods:**

```
    // Event fire die opgevangen wordt in Admin.vue om de tab te veranderen
    changetab(data) {
      this.$emit('update-admin-sidenav-tab', data);
    },
    updateOpenTimesheets() {
      axios.post('admin/fetch', {}).then(response => {
        this.aantalOpenstaande = response.data.count;
        this.laatstBijgewerkt = response.data.timestamp;
        // Fire an event to have the "Openstaand" refresh it's data aswel.
        EventBus.fire('refreshAdminOpenTimesheets', response.data.timesheets);
      });
    }
},
created() {
  axios.get(`admin/fetchemployeewithlastsubmitteddate`).then(response => {
      this.Medewerkers = response.data;
  });
  this.updateOpenTimesheets();

  setInterval(() => {
    this.updateOpenTimesheets();
  }, 60000);
}, 
}
```

Yes, I'm using Tailwind with it if you ever wondered.

So the code is self-explanatory I think. I'm requesting data from the database and inserting it into a table (Not the whole code is shown, only the part where I get data from the timesheet table). The thing is, I wanna know how do I use the computed properly to be getting the same data and then referencing it so the (datum) property can read it as well. I did try it but no luck so far and this is what I came up with:

```
computed: {
  timeMedewerkers: function () { 
    this.data.timesheets.filter(Medewerkers => Medewerkers.timesheets.length !== 0);
}}
```

I am still a junior dev so I might be missing something, I would appreciate it if you don't criticize me for whatever reason. I'm open to tips and suggestions tho. Thanks in advance!

This is what it looks like when fully compiled: [This is the compiled version, it returns the names requested from the timesheet table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIkXz.png)

Comment: It is better to filter it from your backend if you have this access